# Does Java synchronized keyword flush the cache?

Tags: java, volatile, synchronized, double-checked-locking

Java 5 and above only.  Assume a multiprocessor shared-memory computer (you're probably using one right now).

Here is a code for lazy initialization of a singleton:

```
public final class MySingleton {
  private static MySingleton instance = null;
  private MySingleton() { } 
  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new MySingleton();
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Does `instance` have to be declared `volatile` in order to prevent the optimizer from rewriting getInstance() as follows (which would be correct in a sequential program):

```
public static MySingleton getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
    synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
      // instance must be null or we wouldn't be here  (WRONG!)
      instance = new MySingleton();
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming the optimizer does not rewrite the code, if `instance` is not declared `volatile` is it still guaranteed to be flushed to memory when the `synchronized` block is exited, and read from memory when the `synchronized` block is entered?

EDIT:  I forgot to make getInstance() static. I don't think that changes the validity of the answers; you all knew what I meant.

Comment: Hint: you can use `javap -c com.example.ClassName` to disassemble the code so that you can check how it has been compiled and if the compiler has changed/optimized the one or other. I checked it for you with the one of JDK 1.6 and the compiler didn't strip out the nested `if`.

Comment: Using javap is interesting, but the optimizer in javac is usually pretty poor.  On purpose.  The real optimizer is in the JIT Compiler at runtime.

Comment: I apologize for only checking one of the answers as "The Answer". All of them so far deserve to be checked, but it only lets me check one.

Comment: volatile is **not** necessary. public's knowledge of double-checked locking is outdated.

Comment: irreputable, can you explain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `instance` should be declared `volatile`. Even then, it is advised not to use double-checked locking. It (or to be precise, the Java Memory Model) used to have a serious flaw which permitted publication of partially implemented objects. This has been fixed in Java5, still DCL is an obsolete idiom and there is no need to use it anymore - use the [lazy initialization holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) instead.

From [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/), section 16.2:

> The real problem with DCL is the assumption that the worst thing that can happen when reading a shared object reference without synchronization is to erroneously see a stale value (in this case, `null`); in that case the DCL idiom compensates for this risk by trying again with the lock held. But the worst case is actually considerably worse - it is possible to see a current value of the reference but stale values for the object's state, meaning that the object could be seen to be in an invalid or incorrect state.
>
> Subsequent changes in the JMM (Java 5.0 and later) have enabled DCL to work *if* `resource` is made `volatile`, and the performance impact of this is small since `volatile` reads are usually only slightly more expensive than nonvolatile reads. However, this is an idiom whose utility has largely passed - the forces that motivated it (slow uncontended synchronization, slow JVM startup) are no longer in play, making it less effective as an optimization. The lazy initialization holder idiom offers the same benefits and is easier to understand.

Comment: +1 Very interesting. I'm always outsmarted by stackoverflower. This is a never-ending humility exercise.

Comment: If Edsger Dijkstra were still with us, he would probably remark that if expert programmers are always outsmarted by stackoverflow, the profession is in a bad state.

Comment: the holder class idiom only works for singletons. not a general mechanism of lazy initialization.

Comment: @irrep, true, however this question is about singletons, not lazy init in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instance needs to be volatile using double-checked locking in Java, because otherwise the initialization of MySingleton could expose a partially-constructed object to the rest of the system.  It's also true that the threads will sync up when they reach the "synchronized" statement, but that's too late in this case.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) and a couple other Stack Overflow questions have good discussions of "double-checked locking", so I'd advise reading up about it.  I'd also advise not using it unless profiling shows a real need for performance in this particular code.

Comment: (from javaworld article) A commonly suggested nonfix is to declare the resource field of SomeClass as volatile. However, while the JMM prevents writes to volatile variables from being reordered with respect to one another and ensures that they are flushed to main memory immediately, it still permits reads and writes of volatile variables to be reordered with respect to nonvolatile reads and writes. That means -- unless all Resource fields are volatile  as well -- thread B can still perceive the constructor's effect as happening after resource is set to reference the newly created Resource.

Comment: That was fixed in Java5, although it's worth pointing out that in older VMs even volatile won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a safer and more readable idiom for lazy initialization of Java singletons:

```
class Singleton {

  private static class Holder {
    static final Singleton instance = create();
  }

  static Singleton getInstance() { 
    return Holder.instance; 
  }

  private Singleton create() {
    ⋮
  }

  private Singleton() { }

}
```

If you use the more verbose Double-Checked Locking pattern, you have to declare the field `volatile`, as other have already noted.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't have to be volatile. 
See [How to solve the "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578604/how-to-solve-the-double-checked-locking-is-broken-declaration-in-java/3578674#3578674)

previous attempts all failed because if you can cheat java and avoid volatile/sync, java can cheat you and give you an incorrect view of the object. however the new `final` semantics solves the problem. if you get an object reference (by ordinary read), you can safely read its `final` fields.

Comment: Still, the lazy initialization holder idiom achieves the same, in a clearer way, with less code (thus less chance for errors) and without any need for explicit synchronization.

Comment: that only works for singletons. not for lazily creating dynamic number of objects at runtime.

Comment: This question is expressly regarding singletons.