# Can an observable class be constructed as a singleton?

Tags: java, singleton, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm making a program in Java with the Observer pattern (with the help of the Java API). If some of the observables had more than one instance, the program could crash. Should I implement them as singleton? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it before and didn't have any problems exactly because I used a singleton.
The pattern is there to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I implement them as singleton?  Is it recommended?

Of course you can do this.  Whether it is a good idea depends on the actual context.

- Are these things conceptually singleton, or is this just a hack to try to make bugs disappear?  (Or to put it another way, is the real problem that your application design is wrong ...)
- Singletons do have issues with respect to unit testing.  This is not a show stopper, but it is one of the reasons that people tend to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the GoF lists the Singleton as a related pattern (along with the Mediator) to the Observer:

> The ChangeManager may use the Singleton pattern to make it unique and globally accessible.

ChangeManager is their Observable in the sample code.

I have used a Singleton Observable ([here](http://code.google.com/p/memorizeasy/source/browse/MemoPlatform/persistence/src/main/java/com/mysimpatico/memoplatform/persistence/ContentProducer.java?spec=svnc41e86b871326aed70ce7b4428e1ca3b64229d4f&r=c41e86b871326aed70ce7b4428e1ca3b64229d4f)) to update the GUI everytime relevant changes occur to the Persistence Unit. The program won't crash but it won't function as expected if there were more instances.