# Spring singleton class instances created?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following spring configuration.

```
<bean id="abcService1" class="com.service.ABCServiceImpl" />
<bean id="abcService2" class="com.service.ABCServiceImpl" />
```

Will spring create 2 instances with different ids for the above configuration?If yes then  although both the bean definitions are singleton we still have 2 instances of the same object in the context. Would that mean that its not a singleton any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Two seperate instances will be created. Yes this is not a singleton anymore in a classical meaning (one instance per JVM) - (if ever was), however the created bean (each of them) has a singleton scope (in a Spring meaning). If you really want to assure that an object of a given class will be always a singleton (only one instance per JVM) see [Correct way of making a singleton a Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205171/correct-way-of-making-a-singleton-a-spring-bean).

But the question is if you really need 'the real singleton'?!

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the object will no more be `Singleton`.

By default all Spring injected beans are `Singleton`, but if you define the same bean twice with two different `ids` then Spring will create `two` instances.