# Using Java singleton pattern (static access to the singleton) with Spring

Tags: java, spring

Consider this code:

```
public class A {
    private static final A INSTANCE = new A();
    public static A getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    private A() {}
    public void doSomething() {}
}

// elsewhere in code
A.getInstance().doSomething();
```

How do I do the same when A requires a spring bean for construction?  I don't want to inject A in each class that needs it, but want those classes to be able to access the singleton instance statically (ie, `A.getInstance()`).

Comment: That goes against what Spring does. Just inject it or retrieve it from the context when it's needed.

Comment: You may check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205171/correct-way-of-making-a-singleton-a-spring-bean

Comment: afaik, isn't the default scope of spring bean is already singleton? which mean that only one bean exists per spring container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a Spring bean from a static context is problematic because the initialization of beans isn't tied to their construction, and Spring may instrument injected beans by wrapping them in proxies; simply passing around references to `this` will often result in unexpected behaviour. It's best to rely on Spring's injection mechanism.

If you really *have* to do it (perhaps because you need access from legacy code), use something like this:

```
@Service
public class A implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final AtomicReference<A> singleton;
    private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Resource
    private MyInjectedBean myBean; // inject stuff...

    public static A getInstance() {
        try {
            if (latch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
                return singleton.get();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Application Context not initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        singleton.set(context.getBean(A.class));
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```