# Java custom HashMap - Clear method

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created my own custom HashMap for a special use-case, but I am missing the "clear" method.

I have only found one implementation of a clear method for HashMaps on the internet, but I simply cant wrap my head around it.

Can anyone help me? I have provided the custom HashMap and the one implementation i found on the internet.

My custom HashMap:

```
public class LongToOSMNodeMap {
private Node[] table;
int MASK;

public LongToOSMNodeMap(int capacity) {
    table = new Node[1 << capacity]; // there are 2^{capacity} table cells
    MASK = table.length - 1;
}

public void put(long id, double lon, double lat) {
    int position = Long.hashCode(id) & MASK;
    table[position] = new Node(id, lon, lat, table[position]);
}

public Node get(long id) {
    int position = Long.hashCode(id) & MASK;
    for (Node n = table[position]; n != null; n = n.next) {
        if (n.id == id) {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void clear() {

}

class Node extends OSMNode {
    long id;
    Node next;

    public Node(long id, double lon, double lat, Node n) {
        super(lon, lat);
        this.id = id;
        this.next = n;
    }

}
```

Clear method implementation that i dont get, but want to implement on my own:

```
public void clear() {
     modCount++;
     Entry[] tab = table;
     for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
         tab[i] = null;
     size = 0;
 }
```

Comment: What don't you get about it? The more specific your question, the better your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: The overall use. I dont understand how I can use it to clear my own hashmap. Futhermore, the modCount and local tab array.

Comment: The modCount is used to detect incorrect usages of the map (modifying the map while iterating on it). The local tab is just a tiny optimization: accessing a local variable repeatedly is (or at least used to be) faster than accessing an instance field.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void clear() {
    Arrays.fill(table, null);
    // Or: table = new Node[table.length];
}

public void put(long id, double lon, double lat) {
    int position = Long.hashCode(id) & MASK;
    for (Node n = table[position]; n != null; n = n.next) {
        if (n.id == id) {
            return;
        }
    }
    table[position] = new Node(id, lon, lat, table[position]);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I just read somewhere, that it is best practice not to create a new array or refill it with nothing, so that it why, i was looking for a better solution. But thanks!

Comment: A hash table lives from empty cells, so this is an exception. One could alternatively have a list of indices of filled table cells, but that seems over-engineered with maybe no or little profit.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your question to include this quote - a comment does not make a question ;) - but I'll try to answer that based on `java.util.HashMap`:

> The overall use. I dont understand how I can use it to clear my own
>   hashmap. Futhermore, the modCount and local tab array

The `modCount` serve as a mean to detect concurrent modification, which is used when you try to iterate over the map. You can see a use case in the `nextNode()` method on HashMap:

```
final Node<K,V> nextNode() {
  ...
  if (modCount != expectedModCount)
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
  ...
}
```

The local `tab` array is for performance reasons; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222291/java-using-a-local-variable-in-double-check-idiom).

Setting values to `null` is only to help the gc knows that you are not referencing those anymore.