# How to implements DCL without the key work volatitle?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

```
public  class DCL {
    private static DCL staticDcl;

    private final DCL finalDcl;

    private DCL(){
        //other init operation
        
        
        //the action must be last.
        finalDcl = this;
    }

    public static DCL getDCL() {

        if (staticDcl == null) {
            synchronized(DCL.class) {
                if (staticDcl == null) {
                    staticDcl = new DCL();
                }
            }
        }
        return staticDcl.finalDcl;
    }
}
```

can the above code run without any error in  multithreading environment??

I want to use the key word final to implements the dcl not volatitle.

Comment: You made the common mistake of not storing the read value into a local variable. It’s possible that a thread evaluates `staticDcl == null` to `false`, because another thread wrote a non-`null` value to `staticDcl`, hence, skips the `synchronized` block and reads `null` from `staticDcl` in the `return` statement, as without synchronization, the two read operations are not ordered.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* run into problems, see [Why is volatile used in double checked locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-double-checked-locking)

I suggest to not use this pattern, but rather the [static holder pattern (SHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019306/regarding-static-holder-singleton-pattern), which guarantees all the mechanics you try to reproduce. And with SHP you don't even have to think about `volatile` because the JVM handles it directly for you.

```java
public class DCL {
    private DCL(){
        //other init operation
    }

    public static DCL getDCL() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static final class Holder {
        private static final DCL INSTANCE = new DCL();
    }
}
```

Also note that `private final DCL finalDcl;` is redundant because you can just return the instance directly, there's no need to create a new field which equals `this`.

The benefit of this pattern is that `INSTANCE` is instantiated only when it is first referenced, i.e. when `getDCL()` is called. This is due to the nature of [lazy `class` loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4).

Comment: Don’t confuse loading, linking, and initialization. The `DCL` instance will be created [when the class `Holder` is initialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). Since this lazy initialization is the same for all classes, you don’t need the `Holder` class, but can place the `static final` field directly into the `DCL` class and the initialization will happen when the first call of `getDCL()` is made. Only when the class has other non-private static members that could trigger the initialization earlier than intended, you need a holder class.

Comment: sorry, I cannot agree with the point "You could have thread initialize the staticDcl field, and another thread do the same because they don't know that staticDcl was updated. " because synchronized can ensure avoid it.

Comment: @Lino sorry, I cannot agree with the point "You could have thread initialize the staticDcl field, and another thread do the same because they don't know that staticDcl was updated. " because synchronized can ensure avoid it.

Comment: @Holger can show you code? I think his demo is right! because Holder  is static inner class. so Holder  class will not initialized when DCL class initialized, it happend  when Holder.INSTANCE.

Comment: @xanxus the code of this answer is correct. But the explanation referring to “lazy loading” is not, as the field is initialized at the specified *class initialization time* (follow the link of my previous comment). You could run this code on a JVM with eager class loading and it still would work as intended. And once you followed my link and read the specification, you understood that you don’t need an inner class, as lazy initialization works for the `DCL` class as well. The example still is correct, but could be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *without* `volatile`, [it is potentially broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208041/do-we-need-volatile-when-implementing-singleton-using-double-check-locking/61166685#61166685), you can read my other answer for an explanation.

It is rather weird that you have `staticDcl` and `finalDcl`. If you want to provide singletons via that `DCL`, you do not need both. You can read the beginning of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171886/double-check-locking-without-volatile-but-with-varhandle-release-acquire) question on how to achieve that. It also discusses how you *could* achieve double check locking safety without `volatile`, but still with some special semantics like `release/acquire`.

Comment: yes. you are right. but I just want to know can we implements the dcl singleton with final.

Comment: I will provide the global reference with staticDcl and avoid this point  escape。

Comment: @xanxus you do know you can do `private static final DCL staticDcl = new DCL();` and have `public static DCL getDCL() { return staticDcl; }` and be done with it, right? you do _not_ need anything else.

Comment: yes, i know it. it's a good idea. I offen use this method in my work.

Comment: my purpose is not find a good method to implements the dcl singleton . just only want to know can we implements it with final and why or how?

Comment: @xanxus what you are asking is vague, at best. `final` is about properly publishing an object, `DCL` is about singleton factories. You seem to confuse yourself too much here